# JMS serializer loading to much

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm working with Symfony3 and JMS serializer 1.1. I want to serialize Product Object that have several relations:

```
Product
    Images[]
    Recommended[
        Product
            Images[]
            Recommended[]
        Product
            Images[]
            Recommended[]
        ]
```

I want to get all recommended for products, but for recommended I want to get only images, not their recommended. So recommended products should appear only for main product. I tried with MaxDepth() but it only allowed me for "cutting" images and recommended for recommended (both are empty). It would be great if there was a way for applying one Group for first level products and another for second level products. The problem is Doctrine loads all the recommended for the second level and I just don't need that.